# Squid Proxy Server Error : Upon Starting

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, slackware, squid

I got this error upon starting Squid Proxy Server using the command `sudo squid -z`

```
fatal: ipc::mem::segment::create failed to shm_open(/squid-cf__metadata.shm): 13 permission denied
```

How shall I fix it? Im using version 3.5.26 of Squid. 
I tried implementing the fix below I found in the web:

```
 Just add the following line to your /etc/fstab file: 
 shm /dev/shm tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0 
 After that use (as root): 
 # mount shm
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Another possible fix on the web is error reading squid.pid

```
 squid: ERROR: Could not read pid file
 /var/run/squid.pid: (13) Permission denied
```

Unfortunately, as I look in my directory, I could not find `squid.pid`.
How will I get my Squid working? Thanks.

Comment: Are you running apache or Zabbix in that server?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro -> I don't have any. I think should have installed Apache.

Answer (score 2):

You've run `squid` with the wrong user, which created files with wrong permissions.

> squid: ERROR: Could not read pid file

You need to run with `sudo`: `sudo squid`.

> fatal: ipc::mem::segment::create failed to shm_open(/squid-cf__metadata.shm): 13 permission denied

You need to remove Squid's `.shm` files from `/dev/shm` or assign the right permissions.

```
$ sudo rm -v /dev/shm/squid*.shm
```

Also make sure that:

- Squid's log dir (`/var/log/squid`?) is owned by the right user (`proxy`?).
- Squid's cache dir (`/var/spool/squid`?) is owned by the right user.

For the full example, check the following Docker container at [`sameersbn/docker-squid`](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-squid).